# I am trying to convert a date/time string in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, date

I am trying to convert a date/time string in this format

YYYY/MM/DD/HH:MM:SS

to a format that is recognized in PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it's exactly that, just do `strtotime(substr($mydate,0,10)." ".substr($mydate,-8))` which converts it to `"YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS"`, which PHP does parse correctly.

It's the middle slash which is probably the issue, in other words.

Answer (score 0):

PHP can parse that string: `strptime($time, '%Y/%m/%d/%H:%M:%S')`

Comment: This returns an array however.

Comment: That's true, you would need to recombine it for it to be useful as a timestamp, which is usually the most efficient way of working with dates. Nevertheless it does parse.

Comment: That's because I mixed up the date order. Fixed.